# Accent into MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, unicode

I bought a module to dolibarr software and I get a problem with the database module.

My sql file looks like :

```
INSERT INTO llx_accounting_account (rowid, fk_pcg_version, pcg_type, pcg_subtype, account_number, account_parent, label, active) VALUES (15009,'SYSCOHADA','CAPITAUX','XXXXXX','1022',15007,"Dotations compl�mentaires",'1');
```

At the end of each line, I get a description of each one. For example, I get there :

> "Dotations compl�mentaires".

Unfortunately, the character � should be 'é'.

I searched in the module and I found a .lang file. In this one, I have :

> CHARSET=UTF-8

**My question is :** Why I get some � characters instead to get 'é' 'è' etc ... ?

Comment: Would you MySql guys please stop using the Sql Server tag? It's not the same product!

Comment: @ZoharPeled Oups sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the text file use an encoding but defines another one (probably UTF-8 vs. ISO-8859-1). You can use some command line app like iconv or some simple editor like Notepad++ to convert encoding.

Comment: If I understand, I copy `"Dotations compl�mentaires"`in simple editor and I convert it to utf-8 ?

Comment: Open your file with an editor like Notepad++ (which can convert from one encoding to another) and save the converted file. Please, be sure to make a backup of your original file ;)

Answer (score 1):

When trying to use utf8/utf8mb4, if you see **Black Diamonds** with question marks,
one of these cases exists:

Case 1 (original bytes were *not* utf8):

- The bytes to be stored are not encoded as utf8.  Fix this.
- The connection (or `SET NAMES`) for the `INSERT` *and* the `SELECT` were not utf8/utf8mb4.  Fix this.
- Also, check that the column in the database is `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or utf8mb4).

Case 2 (original bytes *were* utf8):

- The connection (or `SET NAMES`) for the `SELECT` was not utf8/utf8mb4.  Fix this.
- Also, check that the column in the database is `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or utf8mb4).

Black diamonds occur only when the browser is set to `<meta charset=UTF-8>`

Comment: Thank you for your explanation ! I'm trying to fix my problem ;)